# Jquery roll over issue with .html()

Tags: jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

So I have a piece of jquery that is suppose to take the html from a sub menu and display it in a roll over (see the image). The problem is, and according the [.html docs](http://api.jquery.com/html/), all .html() does is return html of that element, well I need that html to be "re-compiled" once fetched:

```
jQuery('#adminmenu li.wp-not-current-submenu.wp-has-submenu, .folded #adminmenu li.wp-has-submenu').popover({       
    title: function() {
        var title = jQuery(this).find('a.menu-top').html();
        return title;
    },
    content: function() {
        var submenu = jQuery(this).find('.wp-submenu').html();
        return submenu;
    },
    trigger: 'hover'
});
```

Which displays:

[image]

I would like this to render the html its displaying inside the box. As some of you can tell yes I am using twitter boot strap. The function I have pasted is responsible for giving me the roll over effect you see - with the obvious glitch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the `html: true` option...

```
.popover({  
    html: true,
    title: function() {
    ... etc ...
    }
})
```

Comment: That works until you try to hover over the text in the menu, then the menu fades away making it impossible to use. any other ideas?

Comment: So this solved the problem you actually asked a question the about then? And now you have a new problem that the popover is not holding when you mouse-over the popover itself?

Comment: try adding: `stay: true` option also

Comment: I dont like making threads over silly things, this IMO is one big issue and thus is "solved" partially. Your stay: true did not work.

While the main issue is solved if I accept the answer chances are people will stop responding??